# Error mongodb: $in needs an array

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Estoy modificando la función eliminar en un crud. Originalmente taskID era un solo ID a eliminar; mientras que en mi programa es un arreglo de múltiples ID. No sé como sería la linea de código con mongodb o mongoose para eliminar todas las tareas del arreglo. A continuación pongo lo que he probado y el error que me da.

Método del frontend

```
deleteTask(taskId) {
    var pairs = taskId.map(function (value) { return "taskId=" + encodeURIComponent(value) }); //mi codigo
    var query_string = pairs.join("&"); //mi codigo
    fetch('/api/tasks/' + taskId, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.getTasks();
    });
    },
```

Método del backend

```
router.delete('/:taskId', async (req, res) => {
    //await Task.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.taskId); código original
    await Task.deleteMany({ id : { $in : req.params.taskId } }); //mi código
    res.json({ status: 'Task deleted' });
});
```

El error se debe a que no se como tratar como arreglo la URI que recibo en el backend:

> (node:15540) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to
>   ObjectId failed for value
>   "taskId=1&taskId=2&taskId=3" at
>   path "_id" for model "Task"

Comment: Hola @german, has comprobado que `req.params.taskId` es un Array? 
Segun veo en el Front se lo estas enviando como un String en ` fetch('/api/tasks/' + taskId ,...`

Comment: Entiendo... he agregado antes de esa linea las siguientes:
var pairs = taskId.map(function (value) { return "taskId=" + encodeURIComponent(value) });
var query_string = pairs.join("&");

pero entonces no se como hacer en el backend ya que req.params.taskId = taskId=1&taskId=2&taskId=3

Comment: $in recibe algo como `$in: [ "1", "2" ]` tu estas enviando "taskId=1&taskId=2&taskId=3"

Comment: intenta algo como `$in: req.params.taskId.map((x) => x.task_id)`

Comment: var temp = req.params.taskId.map((x) => x.task_id)
console.log(temp);

me da error:  TypeError: req.params.taskId.map is not a function

Comment: tienes un string cambia el parametro para que recibas un array

Comment: como recibes un string debes hacer algo como `req.params.taskId.split('taskId=').join('').split('&')`

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

Creo que tienes una pequeña confusión en cuanto al uso de `req.param` y `req.query`.

En tu backend, como dices, originalmente recibes un parámetro (`:taskId`) y pasas ese parámetro al método `remove` de tu controlador `Task`.

Ahora, tus requerimientos han cambiado y debes pasar no uno, sino varios `taskId` para realizar un proceso por lotes.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para solucionar esto tienes algunas alternativas, yo te mencionaré una que te ayudará a solucionar tu problema y a la vez te dará una idea de cómo se usa `req.param` y `req.query`.

Otra cosa que puedo notar, en tu código de *frontend* declaras `query_string` pero luego no veo que lo uses.

Empecemos:

Lo primero que vamos a hacer es crear una ruta en el backend que capture `'/api/tasks'` sin incluir ningún parámetro:

```js
// nueva ruta en el backend, la pondremos antes de la ruta antigua.

router.route('/api/tasks')
  .delete(async (req, res, next) => {
    // Ahora verificamos si la URI contiene la query que esperamos
    if (!req.query.taskId) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: 'Nada para procesar'
      });
    }
    // Nuestra API espera una query con la clave taskId
    // y que contenga una lista de id válidos para realizar
    // el proceso por lotes.
    
    let taskId = []; // aqui almacenaremos los id
    let id = ''; // aqui construiremos los id desde el string, carácter por carácter
    
    for (let index in req.query.taskId) {
      // Los valores vendrán separados por coma
      // (los puedes separar como gustes, pero prefiero
      // usar el viejo CSV: Comma Separated Value)
      if (req.query.taskId[index] !== ',') {
        id = id.concat(req.query.taskId[index]); // almacenamos el carácter en id.
      } else {
        taskId.push(id); // Encontramos una comma, guardamos el id
        id = '' // reiniciamos para volver a empezar
      }
    }
    // Si todo va bien, tendremos el array con los taskId a procesar.
    // Ahora podemos procesar los datos:
    await Task.deleteMany({ id : { $in : taskId } });
    res.json({ status: 'Task deleted' });
  });
```

Ya tenemos la ruta en nuestro *backend*, sólo nos falta modificar en el *frontend* para crear la `URI` correcta que contenga los `taskId` en forma de `query`:

```js
deleteTask(taskId) {
  // Asumo que taskId es un array con los "id"
  // Dado que este es tu código, no tengo mucho que explicarte
  // salvo que he quitado el string "taskId=" y
  // cambié el nombre de la variable de "pair" a "ids"
  var ids = taskId.map(function (value) { return encodeURIComponent(value) 
});
  
  // aqui tampoco debo explicarte mucho porque también es tu código, solo que he cambiado "&" por ","
  var query_string = ids.join(",");
        
  // como ves, aqui paso el query string en la URI
  // y si te das cuenta, tu mismo habías intuído que
  // debías usar una query, dado el nombre de tu variable
  //Una cosa que debes observar es cómo se pasa un query en una URI.
        
  fetch('/api/tasks?taskId=' + query_string, {
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    this.getTasks();
  });
},
```

Espero que con esto soluciones el problema. Como te digo no es la única forma de hacerlo, pero si la que te evita menos modificaciones en tu *frontend*.

Fíjate que cuando usas `req.param` pasas la ruta de la siguiente manera: `'/api/tasks/:taskId'` de esta forma Express entiende que estás pasando un (1) parámetro. Ya en tu API debes tener el controlador que maneje el parámetro.

En cambio, si deseas usar `req.query` debes hacerlo de la siguiente manera: `'/api/tasks?query1=value1&query2=value2&...&queryN=valueN'`. Debes notar que una `query` es una lista coherente de `key=value` y cada `key` debe tener un nombre diferente.

En este caso específico, como no sabemos cuantos `taskId` vamos a borrar, pues decidí pasarlos como un CSV en una sola clave llamada `taskId`.

Sin embargo, si tus `taskId` son muy largos y son demasiados, este no es el mejor método para hacerlo, ya que te enfrentas a problemas del tamaño de la URI que puede manejar tu servidor.

Puedes leer más en http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html

Aqui un extracto de la Sección "3.2.1 General Syntax":

> The HTTP protocol does not place any a priori limit on the length of
> a URI. Servers MUST be able to handle the URI of any resource they
> serve, and SHOULD be able to handle URIs of unbounded length if they
> provide GET-based forms that could generate such URIs. A server
> SHOULD return 414 (Request-URI Too Long) status if a URI is longer
> than the server can handle (see section 10.4.15).

> ```
>  Note: Servers ought to be cautious about depending on URI lengths
> ```

```
  above 255 bytes, because some older client or proxy
  implementations might not properly support these lengths.
```

**Edición:**

Como planteas en tu comentario, tus valores de `taskId` serán `id` de Mongo, por lo tanto no es adecuado enviarlos por medio de la URI al servidor, ya que si envías muchos `id` la URI sería demasiado larga.

Lo que puedes hacer es enviarlos en el `body` de tu solicitud, de la siguiente manera:

```js
deleteTask(taskId) {
  // Asumo que taskId es un array con los "id"
  // Ahora apuntamos directamente a la ruta '/api/tasks'
  fetch('/api/tasks', {
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(taskID) // <=== Aqui enviamos la data en el 'body' del mensaje.
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
     this.getTasks();
  });
},
```

Ahora debemos cambiar el código en el *backend* para recibir y procesar la data adecuadamente:

```js
router.route('/api/tasks')
  .delete(async (req, res, next) => {
    // Nuestra data viene en 'req.body', verificamos
    if (!req.body) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: 'Nada para procesar'
      });
    }
    // Almacenamos la data de body en 'taskId'
    const taskId = req.body;
    // Si quieres ver el contenido de taskId:
    for (let index in taskId) {
      console.log('index: ', index, ' taskId: ', taskId[index]);
    }
    // Ya podemos procesar la data
    await Task.deleteMany({ id : { $in : taskId } });
    res.json({ status: 'Task deleted' });
  });
```

Ya con esto es suficiente para obtener lo que necesitas.

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda.

Comment: Hice una corrección en el código, antes el código solo asumía `taskId` de tamaño 1 carácter. Eso era erróneo, pero ya está subsanado.

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, muy amable y detallado en tu respuesta. Pues sí, mis URI serán muy largas porque son IDs de mongodb, y puede haber muchas seleccionadas. ¿Cuál sería una manera más apropiada de hacerlo? ¿No hay una manera más sencilla de pasar un arreglo al servidor tal como es?

Comment: Pues, yo pasaría los datos en la clave `body` del objeto de opciones que pasas al método `fetch`. Luego en tu API debes leer los datos desde `req.body`. Hay muchas formas de enviar los datos. Puedes enviarlos como: `body:  JSON.stringify(taskId)`. Solo debes asegurarte que `taskId` sea un Objeto o un String que pueda ser parseado a JSON. Luego en tu backend ya capturarás los datos del `body`. Espero eso te ayude. Si no queda claro, preguntas de nuevo.

Comment: Mauricio... estoy buscando en la red pero no se ni por donde empezar. ¿Me podrías echar una mano en como hacerlo? muchas gracias.

Comment: German, he editado la respuesta para que puedas enviar la data en el `body` y no tengas que hacerlo por la URI, estoy asumiendo que `taskId` es un `Array` que contiene los `id` de MongoDB. Saludos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Mauricio. Todavía no se muestra la votación a favor porque necesito 15 puntos de reputación. Soy nuevo en esto. De nuevo, muchas gracias!

Comment: Puedes dar la respuesta como válida. Saludos